# proc gplot first symbol statement does not have the right effect

Tags: sas, symbols

I want to graph a scatter plot overlayed by 95%CI, 99%CI and mean value (all three are lines). My code is

```
goptions reset=all;
goptions device=sasemf xmax=15cm ymax=8cm xpixels=1600 ypixels=800 hsize=15cm vsize=8cm cback='00000000' ctext=black rotate=landscape;

symbol1 interpol=join colour=lightgreen width=3;
symbol2 interpol=join colour=orange width=3; 
symbol3 interpol=join colour=red width=3; 
symbol4 interpol=none value=dot colour=black width=3; 
symbol5 interpol=none value=dot colour=blue width=3;

axis1 label=(C=black 'Total Number of Procedures' ) order=(50 to 650 by 50) ;
axis2 label=(a=90 r=0 C=black 'Standardised Proportion') order=(0 to 0.16 by 0.02) ;

legend1 order=('overall_rate' 'upper_95' 'upper_99') value=('Overall Proportion' '95% Confidence Limit' '99.5% Confidence Limit') label=none position=(top right inside) down=4 mode=protect ;
proc gplot data=graph;
plot (overall_rate upper_95 upper_99 rratio1 rratio2)*total / overlay legend=legend1 haxis=axis1 vaxis=axis2 noframe areas=1;
run;
quit;
```

[image: This is what I got]

The data looks like

[image]

It seems like only symbol1 statement does not work, other four are alright.  Anyone know the problem?

Thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `areas=1` option of `plot` statement.

It fills the area under first plot line overwriting on the graph the lightgreen line defined by `symbol1`.